# Ошибка JavaScript "was used before it was defined"

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
    "use strict";
    b = 6;
    a = 5;
    c = a + b;
    document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = c;
}
```

Ребят уже пол часа сижу ищу, может у кого-то тоже была такая ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой. Текст ошибки говорит сам за себя, между прочим: переменная используется до того как она была определена.

Answer (score 5):

Использование директивы `"use strict"` указывает интерпретатору обрабатывать JS код более строго (этот код будет работать по современному стандарту ES5). А у вас ошибка. Вы не объявили переменную `b`.

```
var b = 200;
```

**или**

```
let b = 200;
```

Comment: так поскольку я в этом новичок, я туго соображаю насколько я понял нужно просто перед b поставить var

Comment: Да, я Вам даже пример привел

Comment: ты просто маг, благодарю

Comment: Если уж "use strict"; (то есть современный стандарт), то логичнее наверное использовать все же const или let, нежели var